# Showing the result of "python manage.py test" inside template

Tags: python, django

I am writing views.py function which it should return "python manage.py test" and render it to the template

views.py

```
@login_required
def Test_Case(request):
     output = os.popen("python manage.py test").read()
     return render(request, 'Test-Case.html',{'output':output} )
```

above code return nothing
but when i do

```
@login_required
def Test_Case(request):
     output = os.popen("dir").read()
     return render(request, 'Test-Case.html',{'output':output} )
```

it work fine , is there any idea how can i do that

**thanks for your help**

Answer (score 3):

Most of `python manage.py test`'s output is sent to its [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)). You have to capture both stdout and sterr of the process you're spawning. A good example of running a command and capturing both of the streams can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) as is summarized as follows:

```
import subprocess
import sys



def run(cmd):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
 
    return proc.returncode, stdout, stderr
 
code, out, err = run([sys.executable, 'examples/python/run.py'])
 
print("out: '{}'".format(out))
print("err: '{}'".format(err))
print("exit: {}".format(code))
```

Comment: thanks for your time the out variable print --> b''

Comment: err variable --> b'*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 9) ***\nunable to load configuration from python manage.py test\n'

Comment: hmm. At least the issue is reduced to correctly running the test command. I hope it is the same output if you execute it by hand. Is it?

Comment: Consider running the same python executable i.e. virtualenv if you are using one. And also provide with the common same settings like the working directory and environment variables you which to execute tests with.